# Document will not compile using VerbTeX on my tablet

Tags: packages, texlive-2018

Good Morning,

I am using VerbTex on my Lenovo Tab 4 and have recently installed texlive 2018 as well. I have gotten several documents to compile even a few simple ones with amsmath and amssymb packages. I just tried to compile a much much more complicated one with no success however. I believe it is due to VerbTex not having all the packages. I am not in front of my machine currently just my tablet but I can list all packages in the document:

- amscd
- amsbsy
- array
- color
- pxfonts
- fancyhdr
- framed
- latexsym
- multicol
- pstricks
- slashed
- xcolor
- picture
- identfirst
- enumitem
- mathtools
- hyperref
- tikz
- subfig
- ntheorem
- changes
- tikz-cd
- float
- titlesec
- fancychap

I am hoping all I need do is install all of these packages on my tablet but am not certain as to how.

I've been able to get to my computer and now can provide a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\usepackage[left=1.65cm,right=1.65cm,top=2.45cm,bottom=2.60cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amscd,amsbsy,array,color,pxfonts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,framed,latexsym,multicol,pstricks}
\usepackage{slashed,xcolor,multicol}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\setlist[description]{leftmargin=1cm,labelindent=1cm}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
```

}

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes.geometric}

\setenumerate[1]{label=(\alph*)}
\setenumerate[2]{label=(\roman*)}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand{\NOT}{\sim}\newcommand{\AND}{\wedge}\newcommand{\OR}{\vee}
\newcommand{\twolinebrace}{\rlap{$\smash{\raisebox{.5\height}{\bigg\}}}$}}
\newlength{\LHS}\newlength{\RHS}
\settowidth{\LHS}{$P \OR (Q \OR R)$}\settowidth{\RHS}{$(P \AND Q) \OR (P \AND R)$}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}p{\LHS}<{$}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$}p{\RHS}<{$}}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage[amsmath,framed,thmmarks]{ntheorem}

\usepackage{changes}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[Conny]{fncychap}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{chapter}{-1}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}{}}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont}
{\filcenter
\footnotesize
\enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace}
{8pt}
{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Equation Numbering %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
%code by Heiko Oberdiek
\makeatletter
%Roman counter
\newcounter{roem}
\renewcommand{\theroem}{\roman{roem}}

% save the original counter
\newcommand{\c@org@eq}{}
\let\c@org@eq\c@equation
\newcommand{\org@theeq}{}
\let\org@theeq\theequation

%\setroem sets roman counting
\newcommand{\setroem}{
\let\c@equation\c@roem
\let\theequation\theroem}

%\setarab the arabic counting
\newcommand{\setarab}{
\let\c@equation\c@org@eq
\let\theequation\org@theeq}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Theorem/Example/Definition/Proof Styles %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
    \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{them}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremclass{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\theoreminframepreskip{0pt}
\theoreminframepostskip{0pt}
\theoremframepreskip{1cm}
\theoremframepostskip{1cm}
\theoremstyle{break}
\def\theoremframecommand{%
    \psshadowbox[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linecolor=black]}
\newshadedtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% Sets used in Analysis %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
\def    \bN{\mathbb N}
\def    \bZ{\mathbb Z}
\def    \bQ{\mathbb Q}
\def    \bR{\mathbb R}
\def    \bC{\mathbb C}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\title{Modern Analysis: Real \& Complex}
\author{Micheal (Philip) Dykes and Croix Snap}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Logic, Set Theory, Functions, and Relations.}
\section{Mathematical Logic.}
\subsection*{Introduction.}
    \small{Analysis is all about the theory behind Calculus. In this course, we do not take for granted such notions as what the set $\bR$ of real numbers is; rather we carefully define $\bR$ by ``building" it out of other sets - beginning with the set $\bN$ of Natural Numbers. Numbers and number systems (i.e. $\bN, \bZ, \bQ, \bR$, and $\bC$) are the ``building-blocks" of Analysis. Here in this book, we do not merely state the properties of the Real Number System, but we derive them. 

\end{document}
```

Michael D

Comment: Isn't verbtex just an editor? Where exactly is it compiling your document, locally or using the cloud? Also eaxctly what texlive did you install? the full one? An editor does not need any packages, it just passes the document on to latex. From looking (briefly) online, it is not compiling locally, so perhaps you should ask those providing the service being used.

Comment: It actually can generate a pdf as well.I am not certain as to texlive - the command I used for android tablet was: pkg install texlive.

Comment: I have no idea. What you have running on your tablet. But you need to figure out whether it is compiling locally or in the cloud. Without knowing that, we have no way of helping. If running locally, then installing "texlive" is not done like that. Debian has split texlive into many smaller Debian packages (not always the same as latex packages), do in order to have everything you need texlive-full or knowledge of exactly which Debian packaged texlive packages you need. But first figure out exactly how that editor is handling compiling stuff. Locally or in the cloud

Comment: I am using the local mode since all my .tex files are on my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

TeX Live is a cross platform TeX distribution with numerous TeX engines composed of thousands of packages in total between 200Mb and several GB and there are some users who have had mixed success by using various smaller pieces on phones or tablets. Several lightweight applications for iOS (TeXpad) and Android (TeXPortal/TeXpert a dual app approach to allow load spreading as Android apps were limited to 32MB heap memory. By separating into two apps, they could utilize a whopping 64MB !)

The latest variant from the LAH stable LawTeX uses  ε-TEX an enhanced engine that is a subset of Tex Live packages but primarily uses DVI and PNG in the background at compile time. Sadly the developer of ε-TEX Peter Breitenlohner, b1940–passed Oct 2015

From LawTeX readme

> "It doesn't aim to provide PDF or any kind of professional publishing"
>
> 1. Use LawTeX to WRITE and PREVIEW your LaTeX code; and
> 2. When you are satisfied with the CONTENT, generate the PDF online using VerbTeX.

Modern apps such as VerbTeX allow a small screen editor to provide a simple IDE then transfer compilation to a much meatier cloud based PDF server. hence the popularity of Overleaf.

Unless you have a windows or nix mainstream tablet you are unlikely to have the necessary storage, co-processing power, or full compatible range of packages. (That could of course change in the future, and I may be wrong about current offerings)

"*VerbTeX* allows you to create and manage LaTeX projects directly on your Android device and ***generate a PDF by using the LaTeX service available at verbosus.com***."

This in effect is similar to other online solutions, there are several academic cloud based typesetting systems with various features. 
The more common ones are [Authorea](https://www.authorea.com/online-latex-editor)  [Epsilon / Papeeria](https://papeeria.com/about/pricing) OverLeaf/ShareLaTeX to name but a few and there are more specialist latex editors to choose from such as  [CoCalc by SageMath](https://cocalc.com/)

Comment: I'd rather use local mode - in order to be able to edit and compile anywhere even in places (which happens more for me where I live) with no internet access. Thanks.Also, I have TexPortal downloaded but whenever I try to install additional programs it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: added a bit of LAH history re texportal and lawtex